# What does 'Segment type: Externs' mean in IDA?

Tags: c, linker, loader, elf, ida

I'm trying to analyse an dynamically linked 64-bit ELF file using IDA pro, and I find a segment with an `extern` tpye, which is right after the `.bss`, as follows

```
extern:00000000006021C0 ; Segment type: Externs
extern:00000000006021C0 ; extern
extern:00000000006021C0 ; void free(void *ptr)
extern:00000000006021C0        extrn free:near      ; DATA XREF: .got.plt:off_602018o
```

However, when I debug it at the runtime using gdb, I find that this 'extern' segment contains ONLY ZERO! There isn't any valid data other than zero in this segment. Also, there is no descriptions about the permissions of this segment, it looks as if this segment doesn't even exist.

Since there is DATA XREF in GOT, maybe it has something to do with import functions? But I couldn't find relevant documents, I wonder how IDA recognizes it, and what it is exactly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`extern` is not a real segment. It is a pseudo segment created by IDA to represent symbols with unknown addresses in other modules; the GOT usually contains pointers to those. During debugging it probably gets covered by .bss or stack area cleared by the OS loader, that's why you see zeroes there.

Answer (score 0):

extern in the context of IDA is a bit different than in the context of C/C++.

In C/C++, the `extern` keyword is used to *declare* a variable/function/object that is not actually *defined* in the current object but will be available by the time the binary is linked. This is for when you define an array in one .c file and access it in multiple files, for example.

In the context of IDA, the externs section is used to describe a memory area defining APIs from .so/.dll files. This is usually the IAT in a PE and the GOT in an ELF file. When an object in an externs section has a name of a known API, IDA will automatically color it pink and add the prototype if available.